# How do I overcome the svn error "file is out of date" in SmartGit?

Tags: git, svn, smartgit

How can I solve that conflict?

Each time I try to push my latest changes, I get these error in my svn, which I use over SmartGit/hg.

This is the log in german:

[image]

[image]

How do I get the svn trunk on the git trunk?

What does it mean: "file is out of date"?

Comment: Considering your reputation score, I guess you have pulled already.

Comment: sure. I added a screenshot of the log tree

Comment: This may be a related question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547760/smartgit-file-or-directory-out-of-date-error-message-when-it-is-not/25548180#25548180

Comment: A friend solved this for me on my console with rebasing somehow. I couldn't follow ;) So I guess this will never be answered

Answer (score 0):

Fetch & Rebase again. There are probably new changes that you need to integrate into the file. Alternatively, make sure you have committed all your changes to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve any conflicts in `header.inc.php`, then make sure you *add* (or *stage*) the file.

Comment: That is the strange thing: there are no conflicts left and everything is committed in git, but i cannot push it