# SmartGit: File or Directory out of date error message when it is not?

Tags: git, svn, smartgit

Someone please help me understand my mistake/misunderstanding of what's happening below:

This is an SVN repository.

[image]

As you can see, I have two branches and committed a few independent changes to the release. According to the log above, both server branches map back into the current local release branch which is a few commits ahead.

If I go to push the changes of release back to the remote server. I get the following error:

[image]

It would seem the error is some how related to an SVN problem "409 conflict" but searching around doesn't reveal any useful information.

So I've tried pulling changes from both trunk and the release branch on remote and neither have new changes. Why am I getting an error message that my local branch is out of date?

Comment: Looks like a very old SmartGit version -- please try again with version 6.

Comment: @mstrap I assure you this is definitely the latest version.

Comment: Please try the push again, then use **Help > Contact Support** and include your log.txt*-files from the settings directory (see About dialog).

Comment: @mstrap sorry bud, I've already found a work around as noted in my self-answer below. I can't reproduce the issue either but based on my research, it problems doesn't appear to be a problem with smartgit rather one with the SVN server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I can't explain what caused the problem.

I was able to resolve the issue by doing a soft reset back to the remote release branch shown in the photo above. This resulted in my changes being uncommitted but not lost and I was able to recommit and push the changes without the SVN 409 Conflict error.